# How to convert from IEnumerable<location> to location?

Tags: c#, google-maps, location, ienumerable, geocoding

I am trying to get the location using `geocoding.getlocationasync()` on button click

Here is the code

```
private async void Srch_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Location loc = (Location) await Geocoding.GetLocationsAsync(srch_text.Text);

    LatLng latlng_src = new LatLng(loc.Latitude, loc.Longitude);

    MarkerOptions mo = new MarkerOptions();
    mo.SetPosition(latlng_src);
    mo.Draggable(true);

    googleMap.AddMarker(mo);

    CameraUpdate camup = CameraUpdateFactory.NewLatLngZoom(latlng_src, 17);
    googleMap.MoveCamera(camup);
}
```

But it is showing invalid cast exception - so how can I convert from `IEnumerable<location>` to `location`? Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetLocationsAsync` most likely returns **multiple** locations (as the name of the method indicates) - as an `IEnumerable`. "Converting" to `location` just means picking **one location** out of the list of values you're getting back - e.g. if you want the first entry - use

```
Location loc = await Geocoding.GetLocationsAsync().First()
```

or maybe you want to use (and visualize) **all** locations returned - so iterate over the list of values return:

```
foreach (Location loc in await Geocoding.GetLocationsAsync())
{
    // do whatever you want to do with each "location" returned .....
}
```